# Where are the snapshots saved?

Tags: macos, time-machine, big-sur, apfs

I know that you can manage snapshots with the CLI with the command "tmutil".

Unfortunately I don't know where exactly these snapshots are stored in the operating system?

Edit:

Suppose I don't have a backup hard drive at hand at the moment. Therefore I create a snapshot of the currently running hard disk with the command tmutil under the terminal.

I can view these snapshots later with the command "tmutil listlocalsnapshots /"

The only question is, where exactly are these snapshots on my hard drive? There must be a path where these files are saved? And I would like to know this

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), so can you describe in more details which problem you are trying to solve here ?

Comment: I think the OP needs to learn what a snapshot is, rather than what he thinks it is.  This explanation is not a bad one: https://eshop.macsales.com/blog/56681-working-with-macos-snapshots/